# Can't rotate image in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

Just getting started in pygame, am trying to do something extremely simple (draw a rotated image).

```
import pygame
import math
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1024,768))
helicopter = pygame.image.load('helicopter.png')
screen.blit(pygame.transform.rotate(helicopter, math.pi/2), (100,150))
pygame.display.flip()
```

However this only draws the unrotated version of the image. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the rotate method use degrees ([doc](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.rotate)):

```
import pygame
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1024,768))
helicopter = pygame.image.load('helicopter.png')
screen.blit(pygame.transform.rotate(helicopter, 90), (100,150))
pygame.display.flip()
```